# How to add an mp3 file to a virtual android device

Tags: android

I just started working with android and I wanted to know if there was a way that I could add content to my virtual device for testing purposes . For instance add an mp3 file so that my code in my android simulator in eclipse could locate that file. Any suggestions ?

Update :
Upon going to the DDMS perspective the option for pushing is disabled probably because there is no device. I do not get this part because I am testing on a device and its listed in AVD manager. Any suggestions ? Why is the push option disabled an why is there no device in the DDMS perspective when there is one in the AVD Manager ?

Comment: Problem Solved . Turned out Devices appear in the DDMS only when the emulator is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use eclipse, go to DDMS perspective. there you will see all the devices (emulators) connected. You will have to select the emulator, and click in the right side of the window in the tab FileExplorer. There you will see all the files from your emulator. Copy your content to the folder /sdcard.

You can also push an mp3 file or a folder using adb like this

```
adb push file.mp3 /sdcard
```

Comment: When I went to the DDMS perspective there is no device listed. So the emulator i am using is not even there ?

Comment: The device however is listed in Android Device  Manager